# Operator overloading and setting values

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I created a Container class and used the new keyword in combination with pointers to learn how it works and how I can use it.

```
template<typename T>
class Container {
private:
    T value;
public:
    Container(T value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    Container() {

    }
    virtual ~Container() {

    }
    T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    void setValue(T value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void operator[](T value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::vector<Container<int>*> arr(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Container<int> *a = new Container<int>;
        a->setValue(i);
//      a[i];
        arr[i] = a;
        std::cout << arr[i]->getValue() << std::endl;
        delete a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `[]` operator has the same code as `setValue()`, but it only prints the numbers from 0 to 9 if I use `a->setValue(i)` and with using `a[i]` it prints just a random number. Why?

Comment: I recommend you read [this canonical implementation reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) for overloading operators. Your [array subscript operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Array_subscript_operator) is wrong.

Comment: The subscript operator takes the index as its parameter, and it has to return a reference that the assignment will update.

Answer (score 3):

1. See [Sly_TheKing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587729/1312382) (applying index operator to pointer).
2. The index operator is intended to access values at a specific offset to some reference. It should accept a signed or unsigned integer value and return some specific value. So the operator, to be valid, should look like this:

```
T& operator[](size_t index)
{
    return value;
}
```

Actually, as you do not have anything you could apply an index to (the only valid index in your case would be 0 – or from another point of view, with above implementation, any index would return the same value, so &a[0] == &a[1] would apply - which might be syntactically correct, but violates the semantics of an index operator...), dereferencing operators would be more appropriate:

```
T& operator*() { return value; }
T& operator->() { return value; }
```

Possibly, you could add an assignment operator, too (would replace setValue):

```
Container& operator=(T const& value) { this->value = value; return *this; }
```

Comment: I changed it to                                                                                 
    void operator=(T const& value) {  this->value = value;  } and it works better than Container& as a return value, still correct?

Comment: he is not accessing `operator[]` from class `container` at all, problem is not there

Comment: @Sly_TheKing He commented it out in the question - then asking about why garbage, if using it...

Comment: and I said if he used that commented line, he's still not accessing `operator[]` from class `container`. See my answer to see exactly what I mean

Comment: @Sly_TheKing Saw that already - guess from whom the (at the time of this comment single) upvote...

Answer (score 1):

In line

```
 Container<int> *a = new Container<int>;
```

you initialize `a` as pointer, so with this line

```
 a[i];
```

you just access some memory with address stored in `a` and offset `i * sizeof(container<int>)`

So the correct usage would be

```
std::vector<Container<int>*> arr(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Container<int> *a = new Container<int>;

    (*a)[i];
    arr[i] = a;
    std::cout << arr[i]->getValue() << std::endl;
    delete a;
}
```

With `(*a)[i];` you access `operator[]` you wrote in your class